# Send email with image in the message body

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I want to send email in this format

```
mylogo_image

                                header(middle of page)

content
xyz
asd
abc
```

here is my email code:

```
string emailBody = "<html><body><img src=images/logo.png height=50px width=300px /><br><br><div style=text-align:center; font-size:x-large;>Letter Head</div>";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.xyz.com", 2525);
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ab@xyz.com", "1");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("a@xyz.com");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox3.Text));
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("b@xyz.com"));
            msg.Subject = "Letter";
            String Body = emailBody + "Dear ";

            msg.Body = Body;

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("unable to send message:" + ex.Message);
            }
```

The problem is that it shows only the area of image but Image not showing.
I am using asp.net c#.

Comment: It is better if you show your code what you have tried so far and what exactly is your problem. Usually to send such email, you need to create html version of the email body and send it as email text .

Comment: @KiranHegde please check again my updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to control the format of your email, you should write the email body in HTML.  If there are images in that HTML, then the images will need to be downloaded from your server, so you will need to use complete absolute URL's.  Your email body should look something like this:

```
string emailBody = @"
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/website/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />

<div style="text-align:center">
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/website/images/banner.png" alt="banner" />
</div>

<p>
content
xyz
asd
abc
</p>
</body>
</html>
";
```

Then when you create your MailMessage, be sure to set the body format to HTML, like this:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
email.IsBodyHtml = true;
email.Body = emailBody;
```

Comment: please check again my updated code and then gives the solution of my problem.

Comment: @user3834541 If you check the source of the email, you will realize that the answer was already given for you to fix your code.

Comment: @EdSF please if you know then give the correct answer.

Comment: @user3834541 **Read** the above answer because it already does _"you will need to use complete absolute URL"_

Comment: as @EdSF pointed out, the image URL's appear to be the problem.  Your image URL is src=images/logo.png when it should be src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/logo.png". If that helps, then please mark the answer as correct.